# Does cluster index on time increase the speed of a query where we want the max time group by certain id?

Tags: postgresql, clustered-index

Consider the following query

```
SELECT my_id, my_info FROM my_table as r
JOIN (
    SELECT my_id, max(my_time) as max_time FROM my_table
    WHERE my_time > timestamp '2019-01-10 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY my_id) as k
ON k.my_id = r.my_id and k.max_time = r.my_time
```

And the following table

```
my_table
    my_id [text, secondary index]
    my_info [arbitrary]
    my_time [timestamp with timezone, clustered index]
```

I think the most efficient query if the cardenality of `my_id` is not big would be the following

1. Get the set of all unique my_id from the index table
2. Scan through the entire table from first row (guarantee to have the highest timestamp due to clustering) and fetch `my_info` of `my_id` if not been fetch before.

I am not sure if postgres does exactly that, but I am interested in knowing if having cluster index help with my original query

If the answer is no, is there a way to increase the speed of the query above given the table structure?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no such term as "index table" in PostgreSQL. You can have either a table or an index created alongside a table.

Comment: To see how Postgres plans and executes your query internally add `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE` before the `SELECT` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the clustered index should assist the filtering predicate `WHERE my_time > timestamp '2019-01-10 00:00:00'` but you need to consider explain plans to determine how the query has been handled. You might also want to consider using a window function approach instead:

```
SELECT k.my_id, k.my_info
JOIN (
    SELECT my_id, my_info
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY my_id ORDER BY my_time DESC) as rn
    FROM my_table
    WHERE my_time > timestamp '2019-01-10 00:00:00'
    ) as k
WHERE k.rn = 1
```